# override inherited h1 and h3 values in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS that is being inherited (the original CSS):

```css
h1 { 
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:36px;
}
h1 small {
    font-size:18px;
}
```

I have a class whereby i want to override the `h1` property like so:

```css
.logo h1 {
  font-family: "Euphemia UCAS";
  font-size: 200px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #222222;
}
```

How can I do this without modifying the original CSS? The `!important` value did not help.

link: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3417415/Storify/mockups/screen1.html

Comment: Are your newer rules being declared after the original rules? Also is your H1 defintely within an element with the class of 'logo'? Would be ideal if you could post a link to your page if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "without modifying the original css?"  The two rulesets are in conflict.  The higher priority one takes precedence.

Comment: is h1 definited into class "logo" ?

Comment: Yes, h1 is definitely in class logo, and newer rules are being declared after the older. I am pasting a link by editing my answer so you can see final output

Comment: @KhuramMalik: There is no h1 in the link you've shown as far as I can see...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are applying your CSS selector incorrectly.

Your `.logo` class is ON the header tag itself, from what I can see in your code.

Your CSS should instead be:

```
h1.logo {
  font-family: "Euphemia UCAS";
  font-size: 200px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #222222;
}
```

Just double check where this class is exactly being applied.

Also, just checked your HTML again and it looks like this:

```
<h3 class="logo">Storify</h3>
```

So your CSS should really be:

```
h3.logo {
  font-family: "Euphemia UCAS";
  font-size: 200px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #222222;
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding you at all?

Comment: My apologies. I linked to the wrong file but i'll try what you have recommended and report back

Answer (score -1):

You can use a script element in your html.

Within the script Add an event handler via

```
addEventListener('load', function () {
   // Change your css properties here.
});
```

This way you are  sure no inheritance of css styles can occur.